# Можно ли в одном запросе получить данные с 3-х и более таблиц с разной структурой

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

Можно ли, одним запросом, получить данные из 3-х таблиц,

из первой 1 ячейку, из второй 1 строку, из третьей всю таблицу,

и как потом присваивать значения, в Delphi, если это возможно?

**UPD**

```
Table1
name pass type
Igor 1234 player

Table2
typename param1 param2
player   value1 value2

Table3
N x1 x2 x3
0 5  6  7
1 3  9  1
2 4  2  7
```

мне нужно получить это в переменные Name, Pass, Type, Param1, Param2, myArray

**UPD2**

```
('SELECT table1.pass, table1.type, table2.param1, table2.param2, table3.x1, table3.x2` FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE table1.name= "' + SomeName + '" AND table2.typename = table1.type');
```

так должно получить данные, как ими пользоваться в Delphi?

Comment: почитай про join в запросе sql

Comment: я видел пример, с первыми двумя условиями я как бы справлюсь, в принципе и третье можно постараться, я не понимаю как потом пользоваться полученным. для третьего варианта нужен {while not Form1.FDQuery1.Eof do} а в первых двух всего одна строка

Comment: вы напишите какие данные у вас имеются, и какой результат вы хотите получить. Так проще будет.

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Каким образом третья таблица связана в другими?

Comment: имя таблицы 'Table' + Type = TablePlayer

Comment: @ArtGrek13 это, мягко говоря, не самая удачная связь между таблицами

Comment: `Table1: name pass type`, а потом в запросе `table1.oper`. Что это значит? Вы можете `show create table table1` и аналогично для других таблиц в вопрос добавить?

Comment: в вопросе вымышленные таблицы, а добавил с реальными названиями с проекта, сейчас поправлю

Comment: @ArtGrek13, один рекурсивный член, все равно не понятно, чего вы хотите. Плохо объясняете. Может просто словами в вопросе напишете "я уже три года хочу создать такую-то и такую-то структуру данных в БД"? Ответят вам быстро и качественно.

Comment: Коментарии под ответом дальше прочтите если не поймете, скажу иначе

Comment: `'Table' + Type = TablePlayer` - так можно делать, если количество Type невелико. Но это теоретически неправильно. У вас таблица юзеров, в которой в одном из полей указан тип юзера, которому (типу) соответствует некоторый набор чисел? Тогда не понятно, при чем тут Table3, о чем в комментариях выше и пишут тоже.

Answer (score 2):

```
select `name`, `pass`, `type` from Table1;
select `typename`, `param1`, `param2` from Table2;
select `N`, `x1`, `x2`, `x3` from Table3;
```

Такой запрос должен быть корректным. Его можно передать одной командой, а затем прочитать 3 набора результатов.

Есть вероятность, что следует разрешить где-либо `multiexecute`.

Comment: ок, я намудрил, и так тоже можно,  но как теперь мне эти данные перенести в переменные, по первым двум таблицам проблем нет, FDQuery.FieldByName('name').AsString, а третью? если делать отдельно while not FDQuery.Eof do, а тут как быть?

Comment: Эм.. Я не знаю.